# Is there any way to check if there is a null value in an object or array? mocha - chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Is there any way to check if there is a null value in an object or array?

not using for-loop.

something like:

```js
expect(obj).to.not.have.any.null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [1, null, 3];
console.log(arr.includes(null));

let obj = { key: null};
console.log(Object.values(obj).includes(null));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get all values from the object using `Object.keys`. Then iterate the array and inside the call back call the test function using `not.toBe(null)`

```js
describe('It should check not null', function() {
  it('should not have null', function() {
    let obj = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: null
    }
    Object.values(obj).forEach((item) => {
      expect(item).not.toBe(null)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: yeh, it works. I was more looking for an answer without any for/forEach/loop.